# Get distinct boundaries in matplolib contourf

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to linearly interpolate values using scipy of sets of coordinates, thereafter plotting in matplotlib. How can I achieve the distinct boundaries between each region?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

x = np.random.random(20)
y = np.random.random(20)
z = np.random.random(20)

meshSize = 50
extensionFact = 10
xi, yi, = np.meshgrid(
    np.linspace(np.min(x) - np.average(x) / extensionFact, np.max(x) + np.average(x) / extensionFact, meshSize),
    np.linspace(np.min(y) - np.average(y) / extensionFact, np.max(y) + np.average(y) / extensionFact, meshSize))
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi, yi), method='nearest')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

bounds1 = np.linspace(np.nanmin(zi), np.nanmax(zi), 11)
colors1 = plt.get_cmap('jet')(np.linspace(0, 1, len(bounds1) + 1))
cmap1 = mcolors.ListedColormap(colors1[1:-1])
norm1 = mcolors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries=bounds1, ncolors=len(bounds1) - 1)

im1 = ax1.contourf(xi, yi, zi, levels=bounds1, cmap=cmap1, alpha=1)
fig.colorbar(im1, orientation='vertical', shrink=1, aspect=30, pad=0.03, ticks=bounds1)

plt.scatter(x, y, marker='x', c='k')
plt.show()
```

Presently the intersection of two regions are blurred.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can call `ax1.contour(...)` with the same `levels` to draw boundary lines on top of the contours?

Comment: They are not blurred - there are a few data points between the two extremes and the contours go through them.  Are you really after a Voronoi tessellation?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66502122/how-do-you-create-outlines-to-the-polygons-of-a-voronoi-tessellation-in-python-u